# Por que ocorre esse erro? - invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

Quando eu tento compilar(gcc test.c) gera o seguinte erro:

[image]

O código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct aluno Aluno;

int main()
{
    Aluno *a;
    a=malloc(sizeof(Aluno));

    //Insere dados nos campos do tipo Aluno
    a->matricula=123;
    strcpy(a->nome,"victhor");
    strcpy(a->curso,"computação");

    int *matricula;
    char *nome, *curso;

    //Copia os dados de Aluno para as variáveis
    matricula=(int*)&(a->matricula);
    nome=(char*)&a->nome;
    curso=(char*)&a->curso;

    acessa(a,matricula, nome, curso);
    printf("Matrícula: %d\n",*matricula);
    printf("Nome: %s\n", nome);
    printf("Curso: %s\n", curso);
    return 0;
}

typedef struct aluno{
    int matricula;
    char nome[50];
    char curso[20];
}Aluno;
```

Comment: Você tentou definir a struct no começo antes do ``main()``? Se sim, o que aparece?

Answer (score 2):

Coloque o seguinte código antes da função `main`.

```
typedef struct aluno{
    int matricula;
    char nome[50];
    char curso[20];
}Aluno;
```

Motivo: ele está fazendo o `malloc` antes de carregar a estrutura de dados em si, e por isso está dando erro.

Comment: já fiz isso e realmente dá certo
o problema é que isso é só um trecho de código.

Vou criar um arquivo onde o struct e as funções para manipula-lo vao estar em um arquivo separado do código em que eles vão ser utilizados
vao ser ligados por um header.